# Take first char from \ref{label} and process if it is digit or not

Tags: xetex

My task is about detection what kind of section reference is passed: befor `\appendix` of after one. The appendex [sub[sub]]sections start with character.
See below:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color,xstring,etoolbox}

\newcommand{\getFirstChar}[1]{\StrChar{\ref{#1}}{1}}
\makeatletter%
\newcommand{\makeinbestway}[1]{%
    \in@{\getFirstChar{#1}}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}% <<-- Need conversion of first char...
    \ifin@%
        Section~\ref{#1}%
    \else%
        Appendix~\ref{#1}%
    \fi%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    
    
    \section{Introduction}\label{lbl1}
    \subsection{}
    \makeinbestway{lbl1}.
    
    \subsection{}
    \makeinbestway{lbl2} but it should be \textcolor{red}{\texttt{Appendix~\ref{lbl2}}}. % <<-- ??
    
    \appendix
    \section{Conclusion}\label{lbl2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should instead use the `cleveref` package which will get you the choice of section vs appendix automatically by just writing

```
\cref{lbl1} \cref{lbl1}
```

You can use `\Cref` at the beginning of a sentence to get the capitalized version. And if you want all the references capitalized, load with

```
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
```

Comment: `section #1` is just for human readability. In base case it must be `#1` with section and  `appendix #1` after appendix command.

Comment: You can always do `\crefname{section}{}{}` to drop `section` from `\cref` when it's not referring to an appendix.

Comment: I just double-checked to make sure that you do in fact get the correct output in that situation and not an extra space that you wouldn't want.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `cleveref` like Don suggests. Anyway, you can use `refcount` to check the first character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\tref}{m}
 {
  \regex_match:nxTF { \A [[:alpha:]] } { \getrefnumber { #1 } }
   { Appendix\nobreakspace }
   { Section\nobreakspace }
  \ref{#1}
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \regex_match:nn { nx } { T, F, TF }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\section{Introduction}\label{lbl1}

\subsection{Title}

\tref{lbl1}.

\subsection{Titls}

\tref{lbl2}

\appendix
\section{Conclusion}\label{lbl2}

\end{document}
```

The “search expression” `\A [[:alpha:]]` means “look for a letter as the first item in the given token list.

[image]

You can also do it with `xstring` and `in@`, but `refcount` is necessary anyway in order to have an expandable version of `\ref` and also to preprocess the string.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,refcount}

\newcommand{\getFirstChar}[1]{\StrChar{\ref{#1}}{1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makeinbestway}[1]{%
  \StrChar{\getrefnumber{#1}}{1}[\temp]%
  \expandafter\in@\expandafter{\temp}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}%
  \ifin@
    Section~\ref{#1}%
  \else
    Appendix~\ref{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\section{Introduction}\label{lbl1}
\subsection{Title}
\makeinbestway{lbl1}.

\subsection{Title}
\makeinbestway{lbl2}

\appendix
\section{Conclusion}\label{lbl2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hyperref's `\autoref`.
(For the example below I created variants `\makeinbestway` and `\MAKEinbestway`.
The further is like `\autoref` and leaves the first letter of the referencing-phrase as is.
The latter applies `\MakeUppercase` to the first token of the referencing-phrase.
This might work out as long as the first letter of the referencing-phrase is formed from a single token and not from several tokens. (The latter may be the case, e.g., with traditional TeX-engines processing utf8-characters via inputenc-package.)
You can't use these commands within pdf-strings.)

```latex
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\documentclass{article}

% In case you wish no hyperlinks and no bookmarks within the entire document:
%\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks=false}{hyperref}%
%\AtBeginDocument{\NoHyper}%
%
%  (I know that \NoHyper actually belongs to the NoHyper environment.
%   But NoHyper is an environment only because you normally want to
%   disable the creation of hyperlinks only locally. But since I don't
%   want to disable creation of hyperlinks locally, but for the whole 
%   document, I use the command directly.)
%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color,xstring,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\appendixautorefname{appendix}%
\NewDocumentCommand\makeinbestway{}{\autoref}%
\NewDocumentCommand\MAKEinbestway{sm}{%
  \@ifundefined{r@#2}{\refused{#2}\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}{%
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\HyRef@testreftype\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{anchor}{}.\\%
     \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\@firstofone}{\hyperref[{#2}]}%
     {%
        \ifx\HyRef@currentHtag\empty\else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\MakeUppercase\HyRef@currentHtag
        \fi
        \ref*{#2}%
     }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    
    
    \section{Introduction}\label{lbl1}
    \subsection{}
    \makeinbestway{lbl1}

    \MAKEinbestway{lbl1}

    \makeinbestway*{lbl1}

    \MAKEinbestway*{lbl1}

    
    \subsection{}
    \makeinbestway{lbl2}

    \MAKEinbestway{lbl2}

    \makeinbestway*{lbl2}

    \MAKEinbestway*{lbl2}

    
    \appendix
    \section{Conclusion}\label{lbl2}
\end{document}
```

[image]